# Which template shows the words "Site administration" under the colored horizontal banner in Django's admin page?

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to change the words "Site administration" to something else under the admin page. I tried a couple of `grep` commands but I couldn't find the right template:

```
hobbes3@hobbes3 ~/Sites/mysite/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates $ grep -ri "site administration" .
hobbes3@hobbes3 ~/Sites/mysite/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates $ grep -ri "administration" .
./admin/base_site.html:<h1 id="site-name">{% trans 'Django administration' %}</h1>
hobbes3@hobbes3 ~/Sites/mysite/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates $ grep -ri "site" .
./admin/404.html:{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
./admin/500.html:{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
./admin/500.html:<p>{% trans "There's been an error. It's been reported to the site administrators via e-mail and should be fixed shortly. Thanks for your patience." %}</p>
./admin/auth/user/change_password.html:{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
./admin/base_site.html:{% block title %}{{ title }} | {% trans 'Django site admin' %}{% endblock %}
./admin/base_site.html:<h1 id="site-name">{% trans 'Django administration' %}</h1>
./admin/change_form.html:{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
./admin/change_form.html:    {% if has_absolute_url %}<li><a href="../../../r/{{ content_type_id }}/{{ object_id }}/" class="viewsitelink">{% trans "View on site" %}</a></li>{% endif%}
./admin/change_list.html:{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
./admin/delete_confirmation.html:{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
./admin/delete_selected_confirmation.html:{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
./admin/edit_inline/stacked.html:    {% if inline_admin_form.show_url %}<a href="../../../r/{{ inline_admin_form.original_content_type_id }}/{{ inline_admin_form.original.id }}/">{% trans "View on site" %}</a>{% endif %}
./admin/edit_inline/tabular.html:          {% if inline_admin_form.show_url %}<a href="../../../r/{{ inline_admin_form.original_content_type_id }}/{{ inline_admin_form.original.id }}/">{% trans "View on site" %}</a>{% endif %}
./admin/index.html:{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
./admin/invalid_setup.html:{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
./admin/login.html:{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
./admin/object_history.html:{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
./admin/object_history.html:    <p>{% trans "This object doesn't have a change history. It probably wasn't added via this admin site." %}</p>
./registration/logged_out.html:{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
./registration/logged_out.html:<p>{% trans "Thanks for spending some quality time with the Web site today." %}</p>
./registration/password_change_done.html:{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
./registration/password_change_form.html:{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
./registration/password_reset_complete.html:{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
./registration/password_reset_confirm.html:{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
./registration/password_reset_done.html:{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
./registration/password_reset_email.html:{% blocktrans %}You're receiving this e-mail because you requested a password reset for your user account at {{ site_name }}.{% endblocktrans %}
./registration/password_reset_email.html:{% trans "Thanks for using our site!" %}
./registration/password_reset_email.html:{% blocktrans %}The {{ site_name }} team{% endblocktrans %}
./registration/password_reset_form.html:{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
```

Am I looking at the wrong place or something?

**EDIT:**

After some digging, I think it has something to do with the `{% block content_title %}{% endblock %}` inside `base.html`...

**EDIT 2:**

Here is a screenshot of the words "Site administration" that I am talking about on the admin's homepage.

[image]

Comment: This isn't an answer, but for this sort of thing you'll find ``ack`` is miles better than ``grep``.

http://betterthangrep.com/

Comment: Wow I just used ack. Very cool! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

Give the docs a read; [admin docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) and [customising look and feel](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/?from=olddocs#customize-the-admin-look-and-feel)

Its a simple case of setting up a template for the admin which overwrites the default;

> The template to customize is admin/index.html. (Do the same as with admin/base_site.html in the previous section -- copy it from the default directory to your custom template directory.) Edit the file, and you'll see it uses a template variable called app_list. That variable contains every installed Django app. Instead of using that, you can hard-code links to object-specific admin pages in whatever way you think is best. Again, don't worry if you can't understand the template language -- we'll cover that in more detail in Tutorial 3.

I went through all the tutorials in the Django docs I linked to a couple of weeks back but can't find an example of a custom Admin template, but this site looks like it'll certainly help you understand it;

http://blog.montylounge.com/2009/07/5/customizing-django-admin-branding/

Answer (score 3):

The title `_("Site administration")` is defined the `sites.py` file under `contrib/admin/`. Either you change that string there and have to remember to change it every time you upgrade Django (not recommended) or you override the `base_site.html` template and add the title manually there.

Comment: `base_site.html` only allows you to change the words "Django administration", not the words "Site administration" which is below that. I'll attach a screenshot to tell you what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd add a more up-to-date reference for this old question, seeing as it's still viewed and active, and I find the docs overwhelmingly thorough.

### Subclass AdminSite to rename template variables

> `myapp/admin.py`

```
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite

from .models import MyModel

class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    # this is the variable you asked about
    site_header = 'Monty Python administration'

admin_site = MyAdminSite(name='myadmin')
admin_site.register(MyModel)
```

> `myproject/urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from myapp.admin import admin_site

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^myadmin/', admin_site.urls),
]
```

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#customizing-adminsite

The [properties you can customise](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite) on your admin_site are:

```
site_header, site_title, site_url, index_title, index_template,
app_index_template, empty_value_display, login_template, login_form, 
logout_template, password_change_template, password_change_done_template
```

---

### Extend admin templates

In addition, you can extend the default admin templates:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% block object-tools-items %}
<p>
    Let's nuke this block and add custom content!
    The rest of the default change_form template remains the same.
</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates

Another example of this is adding a custom stylesheet:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block extrahead %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "my-app/admin-custom.css" %}">
{% endblock %}
```

This shows an override for *all* instances of change_form, but you can also override the templates in individual ModelAdmin and TabularInline, etc classes.

---

There's a fair bit of inheritance going on throughout django-admin, so installing [Django Debug Toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is very helpful for figuring out what to extend (and where your override should be placed in the templates directory).